# Files in FTP Folder to HTTP Addresses in txt file?

Tags: ftp, http

I have uploaded a folder to my ftp site. Problem is GoDaddy hosting do not allow directory browsing over http.

I would like to give share this folder with 1 person who is not technically inclined.

Is there a program that can scan an ftp folder and generate http links for each file - recursive for each sub dir?

I guess I should have zipped the folder before uploading, but since its already uploaded, anything I can do to save face?

Creating a limited ftp account is also not really possible with GoDaddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory Browsing would be ideal, unfortunately GoDaddy doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, people who are "not technically inclined" are not worried about whether the address starts `http://` or `ftp://`.

An `ftp://` hyperlink "just works" in (at least) Internet Explorer, and shouldn't cause your user any problems.

You may want to send a link to a (`http://`) website with a link to the `ftp://` address if your user can't be trusted to copy and paste the link into Internet Explorer.

Comment: The FTP Site has no anonymous access on (for good reason).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind sending unencrypted passwords, you can build the login into the FTP URL:

ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/path/to/file.txt

Note that some browsers treat such URLs as "dangerous" and won't start them properly.